# How to detected Control is clicked OnClientClick in ASP.NET C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have an Image Button with OnClientClick event to load Ajax.

I want to detect that my Image Button is clicked. I'll try so hard but no luck.

This is my code:

```
ImageButton imgbtn = new ImageButton();   
imgbtn.Height = 25;
imgbtn.CssClass = "light";
imgbtn.ID = "led" + i;
imgbtn.OnClientClick = "Turnon('" + table.Rows[i]["Url"].ToString() + "');";
//If i can detected that my imgbtn is clicked
//I will do something
```

Sorry if my question is unclear, but i'm try best to show you my idea.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I tried it's working. After creating control you need to add it to `form` and create new javascript function `function Turnon(url){}` in aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function Turnon(url)
        {
            alert(url);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

You need to add control to your `form` or any `place holder` on `aspx page`.
**Code behind:**

```
ImageButton imgbtn = new ImageButton();
imgbtn.Height = 25;
imgbtn.CssClass = "light";
imgbtn.ID = "led";
imgbtn.OnClientClick = "Turnon('" + "www.google.com" + "');";

form1.Controls.Add(imgbtn); //
```